# Is it possible for the mean posterior distribution to be higher than the prior distribution?

Tags: bayesian

Basically just the question. I would appreciate a lot if there was an example, if such thing happened.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  IIRC, the posterior mean should lie between the arithmetic mean of the data and the mean of the prior.  If the arithmetic mean of the data is larger than the prior mean, then the posterior will be as well.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Thank you for clarification! It makes sense.

Comment: @DemetriPananos This is only the case for linear setttings like a Normal model. For other non-linear models, there is no reason for this to happen.

Comment: @user249433 You should rephrase the question because the "mean posterior distribution" does not make sense.

Comment: @Xi'an Do you have anything to read on that?

Comment: Presumably you intend "the mean of the posterior" not "the mean posterior".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure that it can happen. The most obvious example is normal distribution with known variance $\sigma^2$, where for the mean $\mu$, we assume normal prior with mean $\mu_0$ and variance $\sigma^2_0$, then by conjugacy, the posterior mean is

$$
E(\mu|x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) = \frac{\sigma^2_0}{\sigma^2/n + \sigma^2_0} \bar x + \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2/n + \sigma^2_0} \mu_0
$$

Basically, it is a weighted average between the sample mean and prior mean. What follows, if sample mean is smaller then the prior mean, this will be higher then the sample mean.